# Regex for find accent letters that aren't inside html/jsp comments

Tags: java, regex, jsp, regex-negation

Hello I need to find all the accent words that aren't inside comments in jsp files.
By example.

```
<%--This jsp comment have accents áóéí--%>
<html>
<!--This html comment have accents áóéí-->


<h1>This text have accents áóí</h1>
<html>
```

I need to find the accent letter inside the h1 tag but no the ones inside the comments.

Until now I had the regex to find the comments but I don't know how to negate that part.
This is the Regex I had:

```
\<[!%][ \r\n\t]*(--([^\-]|[\r\n]|-[^\-])*--[ \r\n\t]*)\%*>
```

I try

```
[ó](?!(\<[!%][ \r\n\t]*(--([^\-]|[\r\n]|-[^\-])*--[ \r\n\t]*)\%*>))
```

But it didn't works.

How I could negate that expresion?

Comment: I don't understand your full problem, but if you need to search inside HTML for something, you might have to use a parser to cover every use case.

Comment: What do you need to do with them when you find them? Delete them? Or something else?

Comment: While the Anti-Cthulhu regex rant is humorous it is [not a good answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant) and [some think](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant#comment48072_261561) links to it are used in an unhelpful slapdown manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible to match the inner text of each and every HTML tag with a regex.

I suggest using a Java HTML parser instead. [jsoup](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/) is a good one. See [jsoup cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) for more examples.

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to simply delete them, use Notepad++ regex Find-and-Replace (CHECK the box for ". matches newline"):

Find what:

```
(--%?>(?:(?!<%--|<!--).)*?)[^-!~@#$%^&*()+=.,<>|?/{}\[\]\\""';:\w\s]+
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

Repeat that Find-and-Replace until it can't find any more matches.

Otherwise, you can just use that regex to find them and deal with them individually.